# Universal app not rotating on iPad but does on iPhone

Tags: ios, ipad, rotation, ios-universal-app

I have just completed building a universal app which rotates perfectly on my iPhone, but on the iPad it just stands still.

*Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456807/converting-to-universal-app-views-wont-rotate) question, but that does not solve my issue.*

The supported interface orientations are all set to allow rotation and I have even set this in my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; 
}
```

Still the iPhone rotates fine, but the iPad won't move from portrait.

What could cause this, or rather how can I fix it?

#### [UPDATE]

- The switch on the side is not on lock.
- The orientations in the PList are set correctly.
- The Project settings (where you select it via buttons) are set correctly.

Comment: Did you check your Project Settings? Make sure the iPad has all orientations checked. That seems to override all other code.

Comment: Check if orientation of device is not locked. There is switch on right edge of iPad for locking orientation.

Comment: @Rahul, haha thanks, but that was part of testing if the rotation works. Check the update please.

Comment: @LouwHopley yeah, but it happens, sometimes we don't remember that device has rotation lock and we keeps looking into code what's wrong. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding this piece of code to every ViewController of mine:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; 
}
```

It seems like [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456807/converting-to-universal-app-views-wont-rotate) was correct after all. I just thought it wasn't since I checked through all the ViewControllers and found nothing restricting it from turning.

Answer (score 6):

@adam-s was right, except with Xcode 7.x there is no button below the "devices" selector.

With Xcode 7, you need to change "Universal" to "iPad" whereby the orientation selectors change to reflect iPad-only settings. Then you can change the selector back to "Universal".

Confusing!

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to change the rotation settings for the target for both iPhone *and* iPad - note that there's an iPad button to the right of the iPhone one (which some people, such as myself, might miss at first glance):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Adam. Help me a lot.